# root after doesn't call the callback function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement a root.after in a function to give a little time to a sensor to read but I'm not able to make it work. Here is the function code that I can't make it work:

```
def read_wifi():
global graph_data
try:
    del graph_data
except:
    pass

graph_data=np.array([0])
flag = True
while graph_data.shape[0] < 64:
    while flag == True:
        texto='LX'
        connection.send(texto.encode())

        def callback_after():
            global graph_data
            print('a')              
            graph_data=connection.recv(1024).decode()
            connection.settimeout(3)
            graph_data=graph_data[:-2]
            graph_data=graph_data[0:]
            graph_data=graph_data[:].split()
            graph_data = np.nan_to_num(graph_data)
            try:
                graph_data = np.array([float(q) for q in graph_data])
                flag = False
            except:
                print('Error de lectura del sensor. Reintentando leer...')
            if graph_data.shape[0]<64:
                print('Error de lectura del sensor. Reintentando leer...')

        root.after(500,callback_after)                                  
try:
    graph_data = graph_data*m+b     
except:
    pass
graph_data = np.reshape(graph_data,[4,16])
```

As you can see, i've added a line to print 'a' just to check if the code enters the callback_after function but it never gets printed so  I think that the problem is with the root.after(500,callback_after) line.

If I don't implement the callback function the root after seems to work but my tk window freezes every time it reads from the sensor. I also tried to put the read_wifi function in a new thread but it keeps freezing.

I hope I made it clear.

Best regards.

Comment: Why would your code ever exit the `while flag == True:` loop? You just keep queueing `root.after` calls forever and ever.

Answer (score 1):

You never give the event loop a chance to process events, so they just keep stacking up.

As a general rule of thumb you should not have an infinite loop running inside a tkinter program since `mainloop()` already is an infinite loop.

A quick, ineffecient fix would be to call `root.update_idletasks()` inside your inner loop. A better solution would be to refactor your code so that you don't have an infinite loop (`while flag == True:`) inside another potentially infinite loop (`while graph_data.shape[0] < 64`).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The problem is that both loops are in case the sensor have reading problems the first one is ended if the sensor gives all the 64 numbers and the other one ends if it doesn't contain any string.

 Should I write the loops in a different manner? I'm  begginner programing so there are many things I don't know.

Thanks again for your answer.